# How do I constrain an LMFit parameter to only negative values?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, surface, lmfit

I am trying to obtain a bidimensional fit of a second order 2D polynomial function (D(I,V)) using the LMFit package. I need to determine the values of the coefficients of D(I,V) so that I can determine parameters for a model of a non-ideal diode.

D(I,V) = d1*V + i1*I + d1i1*V*I + d2*V^2 + i2*I^2

A link to the a picture of the equation is included here: [Equation D(I,V)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2kw1.png)

I and V are experimental current and voltage data.

The parmeters d2 and i2 must be negative.  I have read the LMFit documentation about inequality restraints https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html#using-inequality-constraints, but I'm having trouble implementing the inequality for d2, i2 < 0 since I don't know what values to set the maximum of d2 and i2 to be.

The model of D(I,V) is:

```
def D_2d(vi_mesh, d1, i1, d1i1, d2, i2):
    # unpack 1D list into 2D x and y coordinates
    (v, i) = vi_mesh

    # make 2D integral difference function matrix
    D = (i1 * i) + (d1 * v) + (d1i1 * v * i) + (i2 * i ** 2) + (d2 * v ** 2)

    # flatten the 2D matrix into 1D
    return np.ravel(D)
```

The fit is calculated using:

```
# Initial guesses for the DIF function coefficients
guess_vals = [1, -1, 1, -1, -1]

# Fit model to DIF function
lmfit_result = lmfit_model.fit(
    np.ravel(DIF),
    vi_mesh=vi_mesh,
    d1=Parameter("d1", value=guess_vals[0], vary=True),
    i1=Parameter("i1", value=guess_vals[1], vary=True),
    d1i1=Parameter(
        "d1i1", value=guess_vals[2], expr="sqrt(1 + (4*d2*i2))", vary=True
    ),
    d2=Parameter("d2", value=guess_vals[3], vary=True),
    i2=Parameter("i2", value=guess_vals[4], vary=True),
)
```

How do I constrain d2 and i2 to be negative?

Comment: Edit: The variable DIF is the 2D data that I am trying to fit

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do

```
Parameter("d2", value=guess_vals[3], vary=True, max=0)
```

and so on.

I should say that your syntax to `lmfit_model.fit()` may not work, unless you've written your own class around `lmfit`.   Normally, one would create an `lmfit.Parameters` instance that contains the full set of `lmfit.Parameter` objects.

That is, if your `D_2d` function is the model function you want to use to model data, the normal, recommended approach would be to do:

```
d_model = lmfit.Model(D_2d)
params = d_model.make_params(d1=1, i1=-1, d1i1=1, d2=-1, i2=-1)
params['d2'].max = 0 # make sure value is negative
params['i2'].max = 0 # make sure value is negative
params['d1i1'].expr = 'sqrt(1 + (4*d2*i2))'. # your constraint 

result = d_model.fit(np.ravel(DIF), params, vi_mesh=vi_mesh)
```

I hope that gets you started...